# Django django.core.exceptions.AppRegistryNotReady: Models aren't loaded yet

Tags: django, django-models, django-rest-framework, djongo

So I'm trying to integrate a model with mongoDB usng djongo driver, and when I tried to insert a record from within models.py it is giving me this error.I'm a newbie and trying to get my hands on django. Please have a look and explain that where and why I'm wrong/ Thank you.

```
AppRegistryNotReady("Models aren't loaded yet.")
```

here are my code files.
models.py

```
from djongo import models

class Iname(models.Model):
    item_name = models.TextField()
    
    class Meta:
        abstract = True
        
class Iquantity(models.Model):
    item_quantity = models.FloatField()
    
    class Meta:
        abstract = True
        
class Iprice(models.Model):
    item_price = models.FloatField()
    
    class Meta:
        abstract = True
    
class Order(models.Model):
    email = models.EmailField(primary_key = True, name = "email") 
    name = models.CharField(max_length=30, help_text="Enter Customer Name", name = "name")
    address = models.TextField(help_text="Enter customer's Address", name = "address")
    
    item_names = models.ArrayField(model_container = Iname)
    item_quantities = models.ArrayField(model_container = Iquantity)
    item_prices = models.ArrayField(model_container = Iprice)
    
    objects = models.DjongoManager()
    
o = Order()
o.email = "jayesh@gmail.com"
o.name = "dhsdb"
o.address = "agdkhdvf"
o.item_names = ['chocolate', 'pencil']
o.item_quantities = [5, 10]
o.item_prices = [10, 3]
o.save()
```

serializers.py

```
from .models import Order, Iname, Iprice, Iquantity
from rest_framework import serializers

class ItemSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = Iname
        
class QuantitySerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = Iquantity

class PriceSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = Iprice

    
class OrderSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    item_names = ItemSerializer()
    item_quantities = QuantitySerializer()
    item_prices = PriceSerializer()
    
    class Meta:
        model = Order
        fields = "__all__"
```

views.py

```
from rest_framework.decorators import api_view
from rest_framework.response import Response
from .serializers import OrderSerializer
from .models import Order

@api_view(['GET',])
def get_orders(request):
    orders = Order.objects.all()
    serializer = OrderSerializer(instance = orders, many = True)
    print(serializer.data)
    return Response(data = serializer.data)
```

And yes here is my traceback

```
C:\Users\ACER\Desktop\invoice\base\models.py changed, reloading.
Watching for file changes with StatReloader
Exception in thread django-main-thread:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "c:\users\acer\anaconda3\lib\threading.py", line 932, in _bootstrap_inner
    self.run()
  File "c:\users\acer\anaconda3\lib\threading.py", line 870, in run
    self._target(*self._args, **self._kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\ACER\Desktop\invoice\env\lib\site-packages\django\utils\autoreload.py", line 64, in wrapper
    fn(*args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\ACER\Desktop\invoice\env\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\commands\runserver.py", line 125, in inner_run
    autoreload.raise_last_exception()
  File "C:\Users\ACER\Desktop\invoice\env\lib\site-packages\django\utils\autoreload.py", line 87, in raise_last_exception
    raise _exception[1]
  File "C:\Users\ACER\Desktop\invoice\env\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\__init__.py", line 398, in execute
    autoreload.check_errors(django.setup)()
  File "C:\Users\ACER\Desktop\invoice\env\lib\site-packages\django\utils\autoreload.py", line 64, in wrapper
    fn(*args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\ACER\Desktop\invoice\env\lib\site-packages\django\__init__.py", line 24, in setup
    apps.populate(settings.INSTALLED_APPS)
  File "C:\Users\ACER\Desktop\invoice\env\lib\site-packages\django\apps\registry.py", line 116, in populate
    app_config.import_models()
  File "C:\Users\ACER\Desktop\invoice\env\lib\site-packages\django\apps\config.py", line 304, in import_models
    self.models_module = import_module(models_module_name)
  File "c:\users\acer\anaconda3\lib\importlib\__init__.py", line 127, in import_module
    return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1014, in _gcd_import
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 991, in _find_and_load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 975, in _find_and_load_unlocked  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 671, in _load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>", line 783, in exec_module   
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 219, in _call_with_frames_removed
  File "C:\Users\ACER\Desktop\invoice\base\models.py", line 64, in <module> 
    o.save()
  File "C:\Users\ACER\Desktop\invoice\env\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\base.py", line 806, in save
    self.save_base(
  File "C:\Users\ACER\Desktop\invoice\env\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\base.py", line 857, in save_base
    updated = self._save_table(
  File "C:\Users\ACER\Desktop\invoice\env\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\base.py", line 970, in _save_table
    updated = self._do_update(
  File "C:\Users\ACER\Desktop\invoice\env\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\base.py", line 1034, in _do_update
    return filtered._update(values) > 0
  File "C:\Users\ACER\Desktop\invoice\env\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\query.py", line 885, in _update
    return query.get_compiler(self.db).execute_sql(CURSOR)
  File "C:\Users\ACER\Desktop\invoice\env\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\sql\compiler.py", line 1783, in execute_sql
    cursor = super().execute_sql(result_type)
  File "C:\Users\ACER\Desktop\invoice\env\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\sql\compiler.py", line 1348, in execute_sql
    sql, params = self.as_sql()
  File "C:\Users\ACER\Desktop\invoice\env\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\sql\compiler.py", line 1749, in as_sql
    val = field.get_db_prep_save(val, connection=self.connection)
  File "C:\Users\ACER\Desktop\invoice\env\lib\site-packages\djongo\models\fields.py", line 229, in get_db_prep_save
    processed_value = self._save_value_thru_fields('get_db_prep_save',
  File "C:\Users\ACER\Desktop\invoice\env\lib\site-packages\djongo\models\fields.py", line 344, in _save_value_thru_fields
    post_dict = super()._save_value_thru_fields(func_name,
  File "C:\Users\ACER\Desktop\invoice\env\lib\site-packages\djongo\models\fields.py", line 155, in _save_value_thru_fields
    for field in self.model_container._meta.get_fields():
  File "C:\Users\ACER\Desktop\invoice\env\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\options.py", line 849, in get_fields
    return self._get_fields(
  File "C:\Users\ACER\Desktop\invoice\env\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\options.py", line 928, in _get_fields
    all_fields = self._relation_tree
  File "C:\Users\ACER\Desktop\invoice\env\lib\site-packages\django\utils\functional.py", line 49, in __get__
    res = instance.__dict__[self.name] = self.func(instance)
  File "C:\Users\ACER\Desktop\invoice\env\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\options.py", line 822, in _relation_tree
    return self._populate_directed_relation_graph()
  File "C:\Users\ACER\Desktop\invoice\env\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\options.py", line 789, in _populate_directed_relation_graph
    all_models = self.apps.get_models(include_auto_created=True)
  File "C:\Users\ACER\Desktop\invoice\env\lib\site-packages\django\apps\registry.py", line 181, in get_models
    self.check_models_ready()
  File "C:\Users\ACER\Desktop\invoice\env\lib\site-packages\django\apps\registry.py", line 143, in check_models_ready
    raise AppRegistryNotReady("Models aren't loaded yet.")
django.core.exceptions.AppRegistryNotReady: Models aren't loaded yet.
```

list of dependencies i'm using

```
asgiref==3.5.2
backports.zoneinfo==0.2.1  
Django==4.0.5
djangorestframework==3.13.1
djongo==1.3.6
pymongo==3.12.3
pytz==2022.1
sqlparse==0.2.4
tzdata==2022.1
```

Comment: remove your model save statements from `models.py`

Comment: CHECK THE FIRST LINE OF YOUR MODELS.PY FILE --- >  from django.db import models

Comment: but i want to save it in database

Comment: and i'm using djongo driver for django and MongoDB integration that's why i'm using models from djongo.